# Place Commas Between Numbers

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm having trouble getting this to work in AS3, I want to place a comma between numbers only when their is a whitespace.

For example, if the string is "1.23 5.34" I want it to become "1.23, 5.34".  The trouble is the white space varies and the number may or may not contain a decimal.  So, I'd want "1 1.4" to become "1, 1.4" or "2.3    4.5" to become "2.3, 4.5".  This also includes negative numbers, so "1.4 -15.3" should become "1.4, -15.3".  If there is anything but a number on either side of the white space, I'd want to skip that space and not effect it. So "Car 35.2" would be skipped and so would (13.5 ).

I've tried several Regexs found around the net and did my best with the limited regex knowledge I have, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDADE**

(?<=\d)(\s)(?=-?\d) (thanks for your comment Tim)

Try the folowing pattern:

"(?<=\d)(\s)(?=[\d-])" (edited to include negative ones)

replace for ",$1"

Answer (score 0):

youre essentially replacing " " with ", "

```
var value:String = "1 2 -3 4 -5";
var csvValue:String = value.split(" ").join(", "); // will print out "1, 2, -3, 4, -5"
```